# Can can I reset an app's styling with a PWA and service worker

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, progressive-web-apps

I have a PWA made with HTML, CSS and JS with Node.js, everytime I change the styles.css of the app, I have to upload it again, I.e. change the port. For example in localhost:3000 it would have the old styling, but if I upload it to localhost:3100, the styling changed to the new one, how can I make it so that cached css files will be deleted and uploaded with the new ones?

This is my service worker:

```js
var CACHE_NAME = 'version-1'; // bump this version when you make changes.
// Put all your urls that you want to cache in this array
var urlsToCache = [
    'index.html',
    'assets/logo-192.png',
    'images/airplane.png',
    'images/backspace.png',
    'images/calcToggle.png',
    'images/diamond.png',
    'images/favicon.png',
    'images/hamburger.png',
    'images/history.png',
    'images/like.png',
    'images/love.png',
    'images/menu2.png',
    'images/menu3.png',
    'images/menu4.png',
    'images/menu5.png',
    'images/menu6.png',
    'images/menu7.png',
    'images/menu8.png',
    'images/plane.png',
    'images/science.png',
    'images/settings.png',
    'images/trash.png',
    'styles.css'
];

// Install the service worker and open the cache and add files mentioned in array to cache
self.addEventListener('install', function(event) {
    event.waitUntil(
    caches.open(CACHE_NAME)
        .then(function(cache) {
        console.log('Opened cache');
        return cache.addAll(urlsToCache);
        })
    );
});


// keep fetching the requests from the user
self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
    event.respondWith(
        caches.match(event.request)
        .then(function(response) {
            // Cache hit - return response
            if (response) return response;
            return fetch(event.request);
        })
    );
});

self.addEventListener('activate', function(event) {
    var cacheWhitelist = []; // add cache names which you do not want to delete
    cacheWhitelist.push(CACHE_NAME);
    event.waitUntil(
        caches.keys().then(function(cacheNames) {
        return Promise.all(
            cacheNames.map(function(cacheName) {
                if (!cacheWhitelist.includes(cacheName)) {
                    return caches.delete(cacheName);
                }
            })
        );
        })
    );
});
```

Comment: We need more details about how you have your PWA configured, if you are caching with your service worker, and what your caching strategy is, if there is one.

Comment: @Taplar I added my service worker

Comment: `var CACHE_NAME = 'version-1'; // bump this version when you make changes.` <= are you actually doing what your comment says?  Because typically the caching strategy to handle for updates would be to have hashes for your files.  And either when the service worker starts up, or the resource is requested, the logic would check to see if the hash of the file matches the hash in the manifest.  If it is not the same, the service worker would then fetch the new changes and replace the version in the cache.

Comment: Related to that, workbox (https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/) has predefined and maintained caching strategies that can handle all of that for you.

Comment: @Taplar can't believe I missed that! Thanks, you saved my life!

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing this for development just open your dev tools. Select the application tab, then the service worker panel.
Click the 'Bypass for Network' option.
I wrote an article on service worker dev best practices that might help:

https://love2dev.com/serviceworker/development-best-practices/

If you need to update in production that is different. I generally do a periodic HEAD request on the network asset (CSS file in your example). If the resource is newer than the cached version I update to the latest version as needed.

I have other techniques I use from time to time as well. It varies by application and the requirements, etc.